# Settings for dotnet test console logger?

Tags: c#, nunit, dotnet-test

I can run my NUNit .NET6 tests just fine with `dotnet test my.nunit3.tests.dll`.

For extra progress info, I specify `dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed" my.tests.dll`, as shown in the docs: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/blob/main/docs/report.md#1-console-logger

*That* works OK.

However, I haven't understood so far if this console logger

- has any other options?
- how to pass any other options?

The linked docs mention:

> In order to pass command-line switches to the logger ... For example:
> `verbosity=detailed;consoleLoggerParameters=ErrorsOnly`

but trying variations on

```
dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed;consoleLoggerParameters=PerformanceSummary" my.nunit3.tests.dll
```

or any other option described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022#switches-for-loggers doesn't seem to change the output.